# Динамическое добавление ImageView по клику

Tags: android, java, изображения

У меня есть `RelativeLayout` с `ImageView`.

У меня есть картинка - красный круг, с прозрачностью 1%.
Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на картинку, эта же картинка накладывалась сверху. 
Делается это для того, чтобы показать количество нажатий на этот круг. 
Добавить картинку нужно динамично, без вызова `OnCreate` метода.

Выглядеть должно так:
[макет тут](http://i017.radikal.ru/1207/09/9059980858f8.png).

Есть идеи, как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо не накладывать, а ставить другую

Comment: Мне нужно уменшать прозрачность круга с увеличением количества нажатий на него. Не вариант брать другую картинку, так как мне их нужно будет на каждый процент прозрачности по одной. И того 100 картинок. Поетому я и использую одну с прозрачностью 1% и хочу налаживать ее много раз.

Comment: Тогда бери картинку 100% и методом withAlpha(int) устанавливай, увеличивай прозрачность

Comment: спасибо) это работает.